# 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown of countries with id #country. I am trying to pass the value selected as a ajax request to a php file - countrycode.php and pass the value received to another input field with id #tele.. My code is as follows:

```
<script>
$('#country').change(function() {
    //var country = $(this).val();
    var country = $('#country').val();
    //alert(country);
});
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'countrycode.php',
                   data: { country : country },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       $("#tele").html(data);
                    }
                });
</script>
```

The alert(country); displays the correct country selected. I tried using:

```
var country = $(this).val();
```

too with correct alert message.

The problem is with the:

```
data: { country : country },
```

i am receiving error:
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement

I tried all the answers in Stackoverflow..but cannot understand the reason why it is not working ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `country` variable is inside `change` function. So it will be undefined for ajax. I think it must be global.

Can you try this?

```
<script>
      var country;
      $('#country').change(function() {
            //var country = $(this).val();
            country = $('#country').val();
            //alert(country);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'countrycode.php',
                data: { country : country },
                success: function(data)
                      {
                         $("#tele").val(data);
                      }
            });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: @user3790186 I tried inside change function. The data is not getting appended to #tele id input filed.

Comment: I found out the reason. It should be $('#tele').val(data); Thank you.

Comment: Updated. @user3790186

Comment: Minor fix if any, but shouldn't the left country be 'country', inside of the data dictionary?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the variables. I'd like to add, you also get the not very helpful StepUpError when trying to ajax a variable that has not at all been declared nor filled. Yes, it might be that easy. I was looking at the working variable all the time and forgot about my copied sessionId..

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to udpate a field with Ajax when the `country` field is changed, then you need to put the ajax call inside the `.change()` handler so that's when it is called.

```
<script>
$('#country').change(function () {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'countrycode.php',
        data: { country: country },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#tele").html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

As you had it before, you were only calling the ajax function upon startup before there was any value in the country variable and then when the `.change()` event occurred, you weren't calling the ajax function at all.